# Expected ')' but when ')' is filled in it causes more errors

Tags: flutter, dart

there is an error and it expects a ')' but as soon as I add it, it causes lots of errors. Can you please help. If there are any other errors, please let me know

```
Widget _buildTodoItem(String title) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 0.0),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () =>
            setState(() {
              _color = Colors.black;
              })); // here
        child: Card(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Text(title),
          color: _color,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

[image]

If I use a comma instead of a semicolon:

[image]

Comment: Add a comma instead of the `);`

Comment: It then causes other errors

Comment: Remove one more closing bracket `)` from line 65 and add a closing `),` after line 72, you can see that in line 65 it says `// GestureDetector`, meaning the GestureDetector Widget ends there which you don't want, you want it to end between line 72 and line 73.

Comment: it says that the named parameter 'color isn't defined on line 70

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
Widget _buildTodoItem(String title) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 0.0),
      child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => setState(() {
              _color = Colors.black;
          })
          child: Card(
              color: _color,
              child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text(title),
              ),
          ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: It says the named parameter 'color' isn't defined on line 70

Comment: It's because Padding doesn't have a color parameter. According to your code, it looks like color is in the padding only. Is it somewhere else?

Comment: Not that I know of, what do I need to do

Comment: I have edited my answer so that the color is the card's background color.